# How to validate a form reCaptcha in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I have a page that contains several forms, by submitting each one of them, next form becomes visible.

the last form contains a recaptcha validator, my problem starts here, if i declare an action result for that page like this

```
[CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult myAction(SomeModel model, string lang)
{
  return View("towing", model);
}
```

I'm getting an argument null exeption parameter "Challenge", which in fact means that you have to POST those fields from recaptcha for the validation to appear and I cannot post anyting untill the last for is visible and posted.

then I've added a news ActionResult like myActionValidated, defined a route for it like:
mypage/validate pointing to that actionresult

and then i don't know where to go from here, i want simply do display a message if the reCaptcha did not validate and redirect to a URL if it succeeded.

I hope I made myself clear. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p.s...[recaptcha in mvc 3](http://ihatethissite.com/blog/2011/02/27/recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc-razor-using-microsoft-web-helpers/)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You must be posting your final form somewhere.  That post action is where you put your CaptchaValidator attribute, not on your get method for that action method.